# Vitamio Projects Export Error

Tags: android, vitamio

My application get an error while exporting.

Application is TV watch.Libraries appcombat,googleplayservice and vitamio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project. Need full code of your Player activity to find a solution.